# Value or else throw exception

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a shorthand syntax for throwing an error if some value is "falsy", e.g.

```
var x = lookupSomeValue() || throw new Error('missing')
```

The above gives a syntax error. Is there any similar shorthand, or do I have to resort to the longer-form below?

```
var x = lookupSomeValue()
if(!x) throw new Error('missing')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[throw](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw) is a statement, so it can't be used where an expression is expected. You could create a function that just throws the error and then call that function as part of an expression:

```
function throwMissing ( ) {
    throw new Error( 'missing' );
}
```

When you want to throw the error:

```
var x = lookupSomeValue() || throwMissing();
```

Of course you could use an anonymous function too:

```
var x = lookupSomeValue() || function(){ throw new Error('missing' ); }();
```

Or using [ES6 arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
var x = lookupSomeValue() || ()=>{ throw new Error('missing' ); }();
```

Comment: I miss "everything is an expression" languages ;)